# Proof/disproof for an inequality in combinatorial relations

Tags: combinatorics

Is the following inequality correct?

${2n \choose 2k} \ge {n \choose k} \; \; , \; \; k \le n$

I know ${2n \choose n}$ is increasing in $n$ (proof by induction) however in above inequality $k$ is also varying. I tried several numerical examples and it seems to be true; but I failed to construct a formal proof for it. I appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{2n}{2k}&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}\\
&=\frac{2^nn!(2n-1)!!}{2^kk!(2k-1)!!2^{n-k}(n-k)!(2n-2k-1)!!}\\
&=\binom{n}k\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2k-1)!!(2n-2k-1)!!}\\
&=\binom{n}k\cdot\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots(2n-2k+1)}{(2k-1)!!}\\
&=\binom{n}k\prod_{i=1}^{2k}\frac{2n-(2i-1)}{2k-(2i-1)}\tag{1}\\
&\ge\binom{n}k\;,
\end{align*}$$

since each factor of the product in $(1)$ is at least $1$.